# Why is my integer always zero?

Tags: android

I am embarrassed to have such a simple question, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to have a level unlock after score 20. The first time the level gets unlocked, I want to give the user a message saying "level unlocked". I do this like so:

```
if(firstTimeOne == 0 && currentHighOne.getInt("levelOneHigh", 0) >= 20){ //First time getting a score over 20
                Toast.makeText(LevelSelect.this, "Unlocked level two!" +firstTimeOne, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                firstTimeOne=1;
            }
```

The problem is, this code executes **every** time the user gets a score over 20... The firstTimeOne variable should be preventing that, right? It is set to `1` after this method has been called, preventing it to be called again. So, why is this method getting called more than once?

I make the variable `firstTimeOne` in my class, where I write:

```
int firstTimeOne = 0;
```

If you need my full code, here it is. It shows that I initialize the int in the class, rather than in a method:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b52a5873b9eb9324e671

EDIT:

Okay, so I am trying SharedPreferences, but get a null pointer exception on `edit.putInt("firstInt", 1); Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5b71982559c245220df

---

```
   //ints will be zero if they do not have a value assigned to them...right?
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_select);

        levelTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leveltwo);

        SharedPreferences currentHighOne = this.getSharedPreferences("levelOneScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (currentHighOne.getInt("levelOneHigh", 0) < 20) {
            levelTwoButton.setClickable(false);
            levelTwoButton.setText("Level two is locked!");
        }else{

            SharedPreferences firstTimeOne = this.getSharedPreferences("firstTimeOne", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Making a shared pref

            if(firstTimeOne.getInt("firstInt" , 5) == 5) { //Check if I've stored values in it yet
                edit = firstTimeOne.edit();
                edit.putInt("firstInt", 0); //Setting the default as 0
                edit.commit();
            }
            if(firstTimeOne.getInt("firstInt", 0) == 0 && currentHighOne.getInt("levelOneHigh", 0) >= 20){ //First time getting a score over 20
                Toast.makeText(LevelSelect.this, "Unlocked level two!" +firstTimeOne, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                edit.putInt("firstInt", 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks so much for everything,

Comment: What does this have to do with arrays and strings, as per your tag? Are you sure it's using the same instance of the class each time?

Comment: You probably want to save `firstTimeOne` to your Preferences as well. Otherwise, it will be zero whenever the Activity is started anew.

Comment: *"although I don't think it is necessary"* It's crucial, as your question gives no indication of where or how `firstTimeOne` is declared or initialized, or what happens after the code above runs, or how the code above is run.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for our reply. What do you mean _are you sure its using the same instance of the class each time?_ I'm not using an object...Let me know!

Comment: @MikeM. Great idea Mike, I will do that and update my question!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't realize that T.J, thanks for pointing that out. I will edit my question!

Comment: @MikeM. But, even if I am not changing screen orientation or doing anything that would restart onCreate, why is the int always 0?

Comment: I have a feeling that that's not your entire class, but if you're calling `finish()` or pressing the Back Button, the Activity will be created anew each time you start it.

Comment: I'm, you are using an object. You're assigning to an instance variable... What instance did you think that was, if you thought that you weren't using an object?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, so I am trying SharedPreferences, but get a null pointer exception on `edit.putInt("firstInt", 1); Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5b71982559c245220df

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand what you're saying now. It gets reset when I come back to the activity. So I am trying SharedPreferences, but get a null pointer exception on `edit.putInt("firstInt", 1); Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5b71982559c245220df

Comment: @MikeM. **UM,** I am trying SharedPreferences, but get a null pointer exception on `edit.putInt("firstInt", 1); Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5b71982559c245220df

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: Code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your int variable is a member of your `Activity` class and you're checking it in the activity's `onCreate()` callback which is only called when the activity is instantiated. Each instance of your activity is instantiated anew and member variables get their default values. It's not the same int you wrote that you are later reading.

If you want to persist data across activity instances, consider using e.g. [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Okay, so I am trying SharedPreferences, but get a null pointer exception on `edit.putInt("firstInt", 1); Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5b71982559c245220df

Comment: Your `SharedPreferences.Editor edit` is not initialized in the branch where you're calling `putInt()` on it.

Comment: So...what should I do. Should I create a new object in the visible scope? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're initializing `edit = sharedPreferences.edit()` before calling any methods on the `edit`. For example in your gist move the initialization one level up from the `if` conditional so it's initialized for both. Also note that you're missing a `commit()` or `apply()` in the latter block.

Comment: Okay, thanks it worked. I have marked you best answer and liked your answer.